# Identity 2.0 with existing Database - The entity types 'IdentityRole' and 'AspNetRoles' cannot share table 'AspNetRoles'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity-2, dbset

I've been working for a little over two weeks on implementing the ASP.Net Identity 2.0 system into an MVC 5 app using an existing database. It has been...trying.

Currently I'm fighting with an error in my registration modifications (and I fear that this is pointing at something larger being fubar - I'm hoping that someone with a better understanding of Identity 2.0 will understand where my issue is)

When attempting to create a new user during the registration process, the compiler would error out telling me that half a dozen entities didn't have primary keys. of these 6, 5 were entities generated by visual studio when I loaded my azure sql database into the project.

The 6th entity (and the troublesome one) is AspNetUserLogin (which is a table that comes with Identity 2.0)

I resolved the errors for all 6 by going in to IdentityModels.cs and overriding OnModelCreate and adding in the primary keys as such

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>().HasKey(c => c.Cust_ID)
```

While this clears up the original error i was receiving about not having keys, this introduces a new issue.

Now when I try to run, I get the error in my title:

> The entity types 'IdentityRole' and 'AspNetRoles' cannot share table 'AspNetRoles' because they are not in the same type hierarchy or do not have a valid one to one foreign key relationship with matching primary keys between them.

I'm not really sure where that's coming from. I don't have a table named IdentityRole. The only places I can find that are deep in the EntityFramework code,and I can't find anywhere that shows that it has a primary key that's been set to anything.

The only connection I can find is that the error occurs when I make the above mentioned alterations in IdentityModels > ApplicationDbContext which extends IdentityDbContext< ApplicationUser> which uses IdentityRole, but no where can I find a spot where it thinks it's getting a primary key.

I will post whatever code is asked for,i'm just not sure what code to post that would be helpful/applicable, and I don't want to overload the page with code.

Ask and ye shall receive. Thanks In advance for helping

I'm going to go continue to mess with it and see if i can fix it (or at least break it differently)

Comment: You definitely shouldn't have to tweak the EF model for the Identity entities; everything is encapsulated in IdentityDbContext already. You mention issues with your own entities; this shouldn't be related. Are you trying to use a custom DbContext with the Identity APIs? (If so, I'm not even sure you got this far; you really have to implement [higher-level](https://www.asp.net/identity/overview/extensibility/overview-of-custom-storage-providers-for-aspnet-identity) Identity APIs in order to do so). If not, you probably shouldn't include the Identity entities in your own context.

Comment: I thought that I had migrated the tables generated/needed for identity properly, maybe not. There are 2 connections to my sql database. They're both to the same tables but one uses system.data.sql (and this is what I have to use in order to get the asp.net identity stuff to work at all) and the other uses system.data.entity client (this is for the entities). Because of that I have 2 DbContexts out there, but idk where theyre interfering. This worked fine until I tied one of my tables to an identity  table. Now its having trouble. I may need to rebuild from the ground up and be more careful